# SIGABRT error Thread 0 crashed iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, crash-reports, sigabrt

Iam new to iOS and have developed an app. The issue is the app works fine when I use it but on the client side it crashes with the following log:-

```
Incident Identifier: 74AEF6C5-98CE-45D3-A7F3-67D54FD66D4D
CrashReporter Key:   TODO
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:         MobileiOS [246]
Path:            /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/F9FF0CF3-DC56-428C-8CB0-40C31A3B4434/MobileiOS.app/MobileiOS
Identifier:      com.mjapps.MobileXam
Version:         1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:       ARM
Parent Process:  ??? [1]

Date/Time:       2016-03-29 08:26:57 +0000
OS Version:      iPhone OS 9.2.1 (13D15)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x20e51c84
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x20e51c84 __pthread_kill (in libsystem_kernel.dylib) + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x20de80c5 abort (in libsystem_c.dylib) + 109
2   MobileiOS                     0x00ac8fc0 0x31000 + 11108288
3   MobileiOS                     0x00a03fdd 0x31000 + 10301405
4   MobileiOS                     0x00a035dd 0x31000 + 10298845
5   MobileiOS                     0x00a027b3 0x31000 + 10295219
6   MobileiOS                     0x009fc45b 0x31000 + 10269787
7   MobileiOS                     0x003de9bc 0x31000 + 3856828
8   MobileiOS                     0x000b8c64 0x31000 + 556132
9   MobileiOS                     0x0008a7bc 0x31000 + 366524
10  MobileiOS                     0x0008b028 0x31000 + 368680
11  MobileiOS                     0x003ab754 0x31000 + 3647316
12  MobileiOS                     0x00a0ce87 0x31000 + 10337927
13  MobileiOS                     0x00a5ce85 0x31000 + 10665605
14  MobileiOS                     0x009a64cd 0x31000 + 9917645
15  MobileiOS                     0x009ab415 0x31000 + 9937941
16  UIKit                               0x256960c9 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] (in UIKit) + 673
17  UIKit                               0x25696209 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:] (in UIKit) + 69
18  UIKit                               0x2568596d -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:isRecursive:] (in UIKit) + 2269
19  UIKit                               0x2569aa47 -[UITableView _performWithCachedTraitCollection:] (in UIKit) + 79
20  UIKit                               0x2543c16f -[UITableView layoutSubviews] (in UIKit) + 179
21  UIKit                               0x2534da83 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] (in UIKit) + 715
22  QuartzCore                          0x23429ad5 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] (in QuartzCore) + 129
23  QuartzCore                          0x234251d1 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 353
24  QuartzCore                          0x23425061 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 17
25  QuartzCore                          0x23424581 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) (in QuartzCore) + 369
26  QuartzCore                          0x23424233 CA::Transaction::commit() (in QuartzCore) + 615
27  QuartzCore                          0x2341d9ef CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) (in QuartzCore) + 139
28  CoreFoundation                      0x2117cb21 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ (in CoreFoundation) + 21
29  CoreFoundation                      0x2117ae17 __CFRunLoopDoObservers (in CoreFoundation) + 283
30  CoreFoundation                      0x2117b255 __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 973
31  CoreFoundation                      0x210cdbb9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 517
32  CoreFoundation                      0x210cd9ad CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 109
33  GraphicsServices                    0x22347af9 GSEventRunModal (in GraphicsServices) + 161
34  UIKit                               0x253b9fb5 UIApplicationMain (in UIKit) + 145
35  MobileiOS                     0x00124568 0x31000 + 996712
36  MobileiOS                     0x000beab4 0x31000 + 580276
37  MobileiOS                     0x000bea74 0x31000 + 580212
38  MobileiOS                     0x000708e0 0x31000 + 260320
39  MobileiOS                     0x003ab754 0x31000 + 3647316
40  MobileiOS                     0x00a0ce87 0x31000 + 10337927
41  MobileiOS                     0x00a5ce85 0x31000 + 10665605
42  MobileiOS                     0x00a6054b 0x31000 + 10679627
43  MobileiOS                     0x00adbe88 0x31000 + 11185800
44  MobileiOS                     0x009b300d 0x31000 + 9969677
45  libdyld.dylib                       0x20d80873 start (in libdyld.dylib) + 3
```

The client does not want to give us a test user hence I cannot debug it. Any guidance where this might be failing would help me in on the right path. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's here: `0x00ac8fc0`.

Comment: @trojanfoe Thanks for the quick reply. I cannot really understand what this is. Could you please explain further

Comment: You have to symbolicate the crash report.

Comment: @trojanfoe Iam using Xamarin so Iam really not able to figure out this. This is my first attempt at ios programming.

Comment: As @trojanfoe said, you will need to symbolicate this crash report to gather any relevant information from it - as it stands all you have is memory addresses. Guide here: http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/

Comment: @BytesGuy thanks for the link. But It says I need to debug it locally to synbolicate it. But I cant do that since it only crashes at the client side

Comment: If you produce the app bundle and you have the crash report then you have everything you need.

Comment: @trojanfoe the crash report has to be from the device on which the app crashed right?

Comment: Not really.  At the end of the day as long as you have the crash address and access to the `.dsym` "file" for the correct version of the app, then you can use `atos` to get the source code location of the crash.

Comment: @trojanfoe how can you say where exactly the error could be. I mean you said its at `0x00ac8f0` how could you point out that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completeness, I'll add an answer here for my blog post that was linked in the comments above by BytesGuy.

You need the .app that you built which is running on the client device. You also need a .dSYM that matches this .app. It's unlikely you have this unless you specifically kept it from when you built the .app file. If you still have it sitting in your bin/Release|Debug folder - use that. If not, you'll have to build a new .app and .dSYM. Keep both this time somewhere.

The client needs to use this new version of the .app file and produce the crash again. Now that you kept the .app and .dSYM that matches it, you can symbolicate any new crash reports which come in using the techniques in [my blog](http://jmillerdev.net/symbolicating-ios-crash-files-xamarin-ios/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried doing it and I could manage to symbolicate it. I get `extra_method_info_offsets ` as the error. Do you know what this could mean?